# Value appears twice in list after nested for-loops

Tags: python

In my code, I have 3 for-loops. They do what I need them to do, but after I print the list 'z', the wanted value appears twice instead of once.

My code:

```
x = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5]

z = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
        for k in range(i+2,len(x)):
            sum=x[i]+x[j]+x[k]
            if sum%65==0:
                z.append(sum)

print(z)
#out = [260, 260, 130, 130, 65, 65]
```

More context:
My goal is to put all the values of the sum of 3 numbers from list 'x' into a new list 'z' if the sum is divisible by 65 (%65==0)

How can I get the wanted value(s) just to appear once?

Comment: You could for example check if the number is already in the list, and if so, not add it again.

Comment: You could use a `set()` instead of a list - eliminating the need for any checks. sets are unique by nature

Comment: your problem is this : 
for k in range(i+2,len(x)): which should be for k in range(j+1,len(x)):

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to fix the output as some of the other comments and answers do, lets try to fix the actual code.

When you do this:

```
for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
        for k in range(i+2,len(x)):
```

you double count some combinations because both j and k depend on i.  (specifically you can reach combinations like 200,50,10 and 200,10,50)

instead do this:

```
for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
    for k in range(j+1,len(x)):
```

and the problem is immediately solved.

This isn't very "pythonic" do, so you can probably do better by using the itertools library included in python.

```
from itertools import combinations

z = [sum(i) for i in combinations(x,r=3) if sum(i)%65 == 0]
```

Comment: added an example of double count

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
print(set(z))
```

It will eliminate all the repetitions, but the elements of the set will be in a random order.
You can read more about Sets [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)

Comment: yes but the result is a set, if you wont a list use `list(set(z))` and if you want to keep the same order use `list(dict.fromkeys(z))`

Comment: Please note that this solves the *output*, not the algorithm used to provide the output.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your range of iteration

```
>>> for i in range(0,len(x)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
            for k in range(i+2,len(x)):
                s=x[i]+x[j]+x[k]
                if s%65==0:
                    print(f"{i=}, {j=}, {k=} = {s=}")

                
i=0, j=2, k=4 = s=260
i=0, j=4, k=2 = s=260
i=1, j=3, k=4 = s=130
i=1, j=4, k=3 = s=130
i=2, j=4, k=5 = s=65
i=2, j=5, k=4 = s=65
```

the k range retrace already traced numbers, make it range from j+1

```
>>> for i in range(0,len(x)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
            for k in range(j+1,len(x)):
                s=x[i]+x[j]+x[k]
                if s%65==0:
                    print(f"{i=}, {j=}, {k=} = {s=}")

                
i=0, j=2, k=4 = s=260
i=1, j=3, k=4 = s=130
i=2, j=4, k=5 = s=65
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
for k in range(j+1,len(x)):
...
```

seems to do the trick.